# I restored my iPhone but it always says Activation Error, what should I do?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore, error

I forgot my passcode so I go on iTunes to restore it, but after the restoration, it says *Activation Error* after I put in the Wi-Fi Settings. I have tried it many times but it still hasn't worked.

I didn't jailbreak my phone, just forgot the passcode so I restored it. I do not have any SIM card in the phone.

Is there something I can do to get the phone in working order again?

Is there any way that can avoid using SIM card?

```
**I fixed it ;)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Activation through iTunes or Over the Air (OTA) is when the device checks to determine if it is factory or carrier unlocked or if it needs a SIM to be activated.

It's almost certain that your failure to activate is due to not having a SIM card from the proper carrier. You do not need to have an active contract or phone number associated with the SIM (I have a 3GS which has an old SIM without a plan), it just has to be for the correct carrier.

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is put in a sim and turn it on it will work perfectly fine.. good luck

Answer (score -2):

well, the only way you can solve this problem is a sim card. if you dont have one, i suggest you ask your mom or dad or friend or someone with a sim card. you can borrow it from them and then take it out and then ur in. i had the same problem. best of luck :)